# What does the star mark mean in TCP View's remote address?

Tags: windows, process

(1) Does it mean the remote address can not be detected or the connection is currently inactive,in which case why it appears in the window after all?

(2) And one more question, what does the "state" term such as,"ESTABLISHED","LISTENING","CLOSE WAIT" and "LAST ACK" mean?

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reminding me, M'vy & Jim.

Answer (score 1):

On the states :

`LISTENING` means you are waiting for connection on a specific port for a specific application.

`CLOSE_WAIT` means that you have received the termination request of the TCP connection and you are about to close it.

`CLOSED` means you have received the ACK signal from the client and the connection has been closed.

`ESTABLISHED` means a communication is on going on the two end of the sockets

You can have a good description [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/janelewis/archive/2010/03/09/explaining-close-wait.aspx) and I advise you to look on the TCP/IP protocol for more explanations.

On the `*` mark, I guess this is because `UDP` protocol is not a connected protocol, so you are not bound to a specific remote address like with TCP.